# Help with raycast node to delete overlapping faces

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to achieve two things:

1. Delete inverted faces (I have this sorted using the delete geometry node)
2. Delete overlapping faces that are not inverted. Using the basic mesh below, how would I go about this?

[image: Delete inverted]

Hi guys, sorry about the lack of details!
I have a subdivided plane with an array + curve modifier, shrinkwrapped to a terrain profile (a flat plane for the examples below).

The goal is to get the distorted faces of the mesh to automatically delete (and ideally join up again) when the curve is altered and the faces start inverting and overlapping, resulting in the cleanest possible mesh profile.

Plane + array setup

[image: Array setup]

Faces starting to invert and overlap as the curve is moved

[image: Invert and overlap]

Area of mesh that needs fixing

[image: Example to be repaired]

Here is a example of a section that has been manually "repaired"

[image]

Comment: Hi AJNZ, i have no idea what you mean and what the problem is. And geometry nodes questions are "normally" answered quickly by experts here. So the problem is your question. Tell us more details what you are trying to do. Show more sketches like "that what it is" and "that's what i want". We don't see any overlapping faces in your image. You can only have inverted faces if the mesh is somehow "closed". So please improve your question to get answers. thx.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Chris. Sorry about the lack of detail. I have added more info to the question now.